# Ajax modal pop up extender with button in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

Hi so I am planning to use the ajax modal popup extender as a means to create a new line in a gridview. Each row in the grid will have a button which will allow users to add a new control above the button (in a new line) they clicked on. This will all be done in memory and users could also drag and drop lines in the order they want. As a result there could be multiple predefined controls that users could add. I thought a quick way would be users click the button, a popup will show displaying all controls users can add (as there is security to this). Then the control selected will be added at the position selected. I have this pretty much working but one thing. How do you make the popup stick to the button it called. This grid could be long, so it is annoying for users to scroll up to select the control they want if they want to say add it to the bottom of the page. Ideally I want the popup to be at the bottom half or which ever button is called it to be on top/next to it. Any ideas

Thanks

PS This is using VS2015, and in webforms.

Answer (score 0):

First up, It is REALLY hard to make a case that you going to have a button on each row, you click on it, and it adds a new row?

I never EVER seen such a UI.

Worse yet? I would keep/hold on to the abiity to build a UI in which a row click "operatates" on the given row context.

So, if you have a grid of custoemrs, maybe you have a button on each row to add a new project or new invoice.

And maybe you have a delete button.

It just seems that to "toss out" this valiable context of oeprations on a row, and NOW introduction of a button that has ZERO to do with that row and context?

I would not "fore go" this VERY common type of UI - buttons on each row should operate on the guveb row and context.

> his grid could be long, so it is annoying for users to scroll up to select the control they want

Gee, then introduce a data pager, or EVEN better, put a button at the very top of the grid to "add new". that way, users can say hit ctrl-home, jump to top of a page, and have ONE button to click on. This will not only result in ONE spot, but also allow users to build up "motor" memory, and for all grids, and all data?

You have one spot, one place, one habit, and one location. That way your UI is consistant. Once they learn one page and how to use - then users will expect that SAME ui everywhere else.

I mean, it is VERY likely that over time, some kind of context or button click for a given row will be required to operate, or select or maybe even to edit that one given  row.

next up:

While you can consider a control extender - (control popup), it does not work correctly inside of a grid view.

I suppose then next, is  you could consider a popup extender , and that pops the dialog in the center of the page.

If you were not using a gridview, then the ajax extender probably not a bad idea. And I have used the control extendor to produce search dialogs from the heading of the grid. But there is only ONE header.

So, give the above issues?

I would adopt the jquery.UI dialog. It works nice with a grid, it can be passed the current row button you click (for the correct position on the web page), and it going to be more flexible anyway.

If the ajaxtoolkit popup had better control of the screen location (it does not), then I would consider using it here.

However, the jQuery.UI dialog tends to work better, gives you more control, and better yet, will play nice with the GV.

So, lets create a grid, and add say a popup edit button.

So, we have this grid view:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"    />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"  />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hotel Information" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="Info" CssClass="btn" 
                            OnClick="cmdView_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

code to load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim rstData As DataTable
    rstData = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName")
    GHotels.DataSource = rstData
    GHotels.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And we now have this:

[image]

so, as noted, lets use jquery.UI (we probably have jquery, so not a big deal).

so, we have to drop in a div that we pop to edit the one row.

So, say this markup (just below the gv).

```
    <div id="HotelInfo" runat="server" 
        style="float:left;display: normal;border:solid;padding:15px;background-color:white;width:48%"
        clientidmode="Static" >
        <style>
            .iForm label {display:inline-block;width:120px}
            .iForm input {border-radius:8px;border-width:1px;margin-bottom:10px}                
            .iForm textarea {border-radius:8px;border-width:1px;margin-bottom:10px}     
            .iForm input[type=checkbox] {margin-right:4px}
        </style>

        <div style="float:left" class="iForm">
                <label>HotelName</label><asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server"  width="280"></asp:TextBox> <br />
                <label>First Name</label><asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server"  width="280"></asp:TextBox> <br />
                <label>Last Name</label><asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server"  width="280"></asp:TextBox> <br />

                <label>City</label><asp:TextBox ID="tCity" runat="server"  Width="140"></asp:TextBox> <br />
                <label>Province</label><asp:TextBox ID="tProvince" runat="server"  Width="75"></asp:TextBox> <br />
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px" class="iForm">
            <label>Description</label> <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" Width="450" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                Height="150px"  ></asp:TextBox> <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" Text=" Active" runat="server" TextAlign="Right" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBalcony"  Text=" Has Balcony" runat="server" TextAlign="Right" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSmoking" Text="Smoking Rooms" runat="server" TextAlign="Right" />
        </div>

        <div style="clear:both">
            <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn" />
            <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn"
                style="margin-left:20px" OnClientClick="$('#HotelInfo').dialog('close');return false;"
                />
            <asp:Button ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CssClass="btn"
                style="margin-left:40px"
                />
        </div>
    </div>
```

And now we wire up the row button click. Keep in mind we can't double click on the button in the GV to create the event. but, we can just type in onclick="" and inteli-sense will pop the option to create the click event. Eg like this:

[image]

So, the code to load up the div, and pop it?

this code:

```
 Protected Sub cmdView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' Row click - get hotel informaton, fill out the pop div
    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer

    Dim intPK As Integer = GHotels.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")
    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = " & intPK)

    With rstData.Rows(0)
        txtHotel.Text = .Item("HotelName").ToString
        txtFirst.Text = .Item("FirstName").ToString
        txtLast.Text = .Item("LastName").ToString
        tCity.Text = .Item("City").ToString
        tProvince.Text = .Item("Province").ToString
        chkActive.Checked = .Item("Active")
        chkBalcony.Checked = .Item("Balcony")
        chkSmoking.Checked = .Item("Smoking")
        txtNotes.Text = .Item("Description")
    End With

    ' ok, div information filled out, now call our js pop function.
    Dim strHotelName = """Edit Information for " & rstData.Rows(0).Item("HotelName") & """"
    Dim strJavaScript As String = "popinfo(" & btn.ClientID & "," & strHotelName & ");"

    ViewState("rstData") = rstData
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "My Pop script", strJavaScript, True)

End Sub
```

And since I pass the button to the pop routine, then the div pops to the lower right position of the button clicked.

The client side code is this:

```
    <script>
        function popinfo(pbtn, strHotelName) {

            // btn = row buttion - we use that for position of pop
            btn = $(pbtn)
            myDialog = $("#HotelInfo")
            myDialog.dialog({
                title: strHotelName,
                modal: true,
                position: { my: "left top", at: "right bottom", of: btn },
                width: "48%",
                appendTo: 'form'
            })
        }
    </script>
```

and now we get/see this:

[image]

The save edit button, is this:

```
 Protected Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
    Dim rstData As DataTable = ViewState("rstData")

    With rstData.Rows(0)
        .Item("HotelName") = txtHotel.Text
        .Item("FirstName") = txtFirst.Text
        .Item("LastName") = txtLast.Text
        .Item("City") = tCity.Text
        .Item("Province") = tProvince.Text
        .Item("Active") = chkActive.Checked
        .Item("Balcony") = chkBalcony.Checked
        .Item("Smoking") = chkSmoking.Checked
        .Item("Description") = txtNotes.Text
    End With

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA", conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daU As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Update(rstData)
        End Using
    End Using


    LoadGrid()
End Sub
```

so, the only part of your question that is missing?

we need that add new row button. As I stated, I don't think we should have such a button on each row.

but, I'll post the code, and its up to you - add a button to each row of the GV if you wish.

So, our add new row button, I'll place it at the top of the GV.

Lets re-purpose our edit one, to allow both add or edit.

So, code is this:

```
 Protected Sub cmdView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' Row click - get hotel informaton, fill out the pop div
    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer

    Dim intPK As Integer = GHotels.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")
    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = " & intPK)


    Call EditOne(rstData, btn)


End Sub

Sub EditOne(rstData As DataTable, btn As Button)

    With rstData.Rows(0)
        txtHotel.Text = .Item("HotelName").ToString
        txtFirst.Text = .Item("FirstName").ToString
        txtLast.Text = .Item("LastName").ToString
        tCity.Text = .Item("City").ToString
        tProvince.Text = .Item("Province").ToString
        chkActive.Checked = .Item("Active")
        chkBalcony.Checked = .Item("Balcony")
        chkSmoking.Checked = .Item("Smoking")
        txtNotes.Text = .Item("Description").ToString
    End With

    ' ok, div information filled out, now call our js pop function.
    Dim strHotelName = """Edit Information for " & rstData.Rows(0).Item("HotelName") & """"
    Dim strJavaScript As String = "popinfo(" & btn.ClientID & "," & strHotelName & ");"

    ViewState("rstData") = rstData
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "My Pop script", strJavaScript, True)


End Sub
```

And to add new, this:

```
 Protected Sub cmdAddNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdAddNew.Click

    Dim btn As Button = sender

    Dim rstdata As DataTable = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA where ID = 0")
    Dim OneNewRow As DataRow = rstdata.NewRow

    OneNewRow("HotelName") = "New hotel"
    OneNewRow("Active") = True
    OneNewRow("Balcony") = False
    OneNewRow("Smoking") = False

    rstdata.Rows.Add(OneNewRow)
    Call EditOne(rstdata, btn)

End Sub
```

So, now, if we hit add new, we get this:

[image]

so, we have a add new at the top of the grid.

[image]

But, I don't see why the Add new button at the top could not be placed on each row - it will work, but I think it is confusing.

In above, we only missing a delete row button - and we again could use the jQuery.UI dialog to pop a confirmation dialog.

I think that's all the code. the other handy routine I used was to get a data table, since I became rather fast tired of typing the same code over and over, so I have this helper:

```
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            rstData.TableName = strSQL
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function
```

So, while I use the one row button for a edit, you can do the same for a add new, the code would be the same - the trick is we pass the button id, and then use the jQuery.UI "position" option - so it works nice, and that is quite much reason alone to use juQuery.UI over that of the ajaxtoolkit pop extendor.

Comment: So the thing is, I am using a gridview to show a bunch of controls on the form. So we have a control which is made up of numerous things (asp.net controls). Each thing is added to make up the control. If you imagine a drawing editor, the idea is like the editor you might want to add a line or a textbox or a label. We don't have the luxury of an editor so we are using grids to display it and then its of case of asking users where they want to add their next piece (asp.net control). We could do it with adding it at one place but then we suddenly have to ask them where they want it.

Comment: Display a dialog or popup - with some controls on the grid, and positioned on the give row (as my example shows) is a mount Everest and MASSIVE different goal then that of dynamic adding controls to some row below. A grid view is not at all appropriate, since you suggest that you don't know ahead of time what type of control you plan to add. That's not a table, nor is it anything remote like a grid view. I perhaps suggest you try truck driving school, or maybe cooking school - but a grid view certainly does not fit the bill as to what you looking for, and you now have a vast different question

Comment: If the goal is to pop some dialog - no problem. but, you seem to suggest that this dialog will THEN allow the user to add new controls to the grid? As I stated, this seems very different goal here. I would consider a listview in place of a grid view if that is the goal. it just not at all clear what type of controls you need to inject to that grid, and how this UI supposed to work.

Comment: Ok, so as stated previously we have one grid of asp.net controls. These controls are added to the grid by users then saved in a dB. Initially I was thinking adding a button on the each row to allow users to add a new row in the grid by having a button on each row. The reason for a button on each over one button at the top or bottom of the grid is that I want to give greater UX to allow users to change the positions of controls in the grid. It is completely silly to ask a user to add a control to the bottom of the grid which could be in the 100s when they want it in position 5.

Comment: The dialog box is a means of asking users what they want to add

Comment: But you suggesting that you not trying to add data, but inject additional controls - a mount Everest of a different task and problem. As the sample shows, pop a dialog to edit data - no problem. But, you not suggesting to add or edit data, but are suggesting that additional controls are to be injected to the grid view? That's not only a a different goal but one that suggests you need somthing other then a grid view for this. I suppose it depends on what kind of markup you trying to add, but you want to do this at data level. UI is for UI only. Add new row of data - sure, do that at data level

Comment: If that dialog pop is to enter more data, then fine. Add the data, and then re-bind the grid then. So, as long as you talking about adding a new data row, then do that at the data level, and then re-bind grid to display that new row of data. That's easy, but as noted, keep data operations and that of gv render as separate concepts.

Comment: so, sure, in above sample, move the add new row button to each row - that wlll work as posted. You add the new row, re-bind, and that new row should show. So, nothing in that posted sample is stopping you from moving the sample "add new" row to a button that appears on each row. The code as posted should in fact work.